# Como o Whatsapp consegue inserir Emojis na URL?

Tags: url

Se pesquisar por "Whatsapp" no Google, o resultado é este:

<kbd>[image: [Whatsapp Web]</kbd>

Aparentemente esse "" na url é um recurso que faz a internacionalização da aplicação web. Depois de acessar essa página, o visitante é redirecionado para o site na linguagem correta.

A minha curiosidade é: como fazer para utilizar um emoji para identificar um recurso ao invés de um texto como `/do?localizacao=pt`? É alguma configuração no servidor? Reescrita de URL?

Comment: Considerando que URLs pode ser escritos com Unicode, fica fácil, certo?

Comment: 
Isso é muito interessante! Pensei que os unicodes eram só aqueles "ALT + 1..." que aparece uma carinha, mas parece que agora os Emojis também foram padronizados. Achei legal isso, encontrei esta página: http://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%F0%9F%8C%90 Note que o "%F0%9F%8C%90" é o desenho do globo que você citou na pergunta.
E se você clicar no site, é o globo na representação UTF-8.

Comment: Sobre o: _"Aparentemente esse "" na url é um recurso que faz a internacionalização da aplicação web"_ - o globo é um caractere como qq outro. podiam ter escolhido um "Y"  ou "Ç3" que ia dar na mesma.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Não precisa de nada complicado. Basta que seu script de rotas redirecione o emoji para o lugar certo, ou mesmo que você crie um arquivo ou diretório cujo nome seja o próprio emoji.

Não tem nada de diferente um "✓.php" de um "index.php" ou ".php", são meros caracteres. Inclusive, se a fonte usada pelo seu OS tiver suporte a isso, você vai ver o globinho pelo explorer ou shell do sistema.

Um exemplo bobo com PHP, supondo que você use URL amigavel:

```
if( $caminho == "blog" ) {
    header( "Location: //example.com/blog.php" );
    exit();
} elseif( $caminho == "" ) {
    header( "Location: //example.com/postagens_felizes.php" );
    exit();
} elseif( $caminho == "" ) {
    header( "Location: //example.com/stevejobs.php" );
    exit();
} elseif( $caminho == "♥" ) {
    echo "eu amo esse site";
...
```

Notou o "♥" no código? É a mesma coisa com o globo. Usei ♥ como exemplo por ser um caractere muito mais difundido que o globinho, então fica mais fácil de todo mundo ler o exemplo.

Vale notar que o fato do globo ser coloridinho no resultado da busca até um tempo foi um filtro que trocava os caracteres por uma versão com imagens, não só para garantir a compatibilidade, mas também para atender os anseios da nova geração "internética". Atualmente a grande maioria dos browsers adota o próprio set de ícones coloridos nativamente.

Isso acontecia em outros contextos em outros grandes *players* do mercado, e não só para URLs. (por exemplo, o Google Mail agora tem essas <strike>coisas chatas</strike> imagenzinhas legais no "assunto" dos emails também, já faz um tempo).

De curiosidade, estas tabelas em especial costumam ter símbolos coloridos em praticamente todas as implementações "modernas":

> https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/emoticons/

> https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/miscellaneous-symbols-and-pictographs/

Experimente copiar alguns e colar na barra de endereços do navegador.

### Cuidado com o *filesystem*!

Caso o *filesystem* do seu OS esteja com um encoding diferente do servidor de HTTP, quase sempre uma conversão resolve (desde que o nome resultante não coincida com caracteres especiais do *filesystem*). Por exemplo, O unicode do `♫` é equivalente a `â™«` em ISO-8859-1. Não vou entrar em muitos detalhes, pois isso é um mero detalhe de implementação, e não guarda relação direta com a pergunta. Além disso, é bem provável que alguém usando esta funcionalidade vá gerenciar os *emoji* pela linguagem de programação, e não com arquivos e pastas.

Answer (score 11):

## [é um símbolo Unicode](http://unicode-table.com/en/1F310/)

```
U+1F310 =  | GLOBE WITH MERIDIANS
11110000 10011111 10001100 10010000
```

Utilizar esse símbolo [força agentes do usuário, como os Internet Explorers de 5 a 8, a codificar a requisição HTTP usando UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3222013/512904). Utilizar algo como `/do?localizacao=pt` não teria esse efeito.

A [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) exige que os símbolos não codificáveis em ASCII sejam recodificados em UTF-8 e então expressos em ASCII na forma do [código em porcentagem](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o_por_cent).

é um símbolo incompatível com ASCII e são necessários 4 octetos para codificá-lo em UTF-8. Apesar disso, ele não aparece na URI como `%F0%9F%8C%90` mas sim na sua forma original.

Isso ocorre porque a página de resultados do Google mostra o símbolo na sua forma original para o usuário. O link realiza a seguinte requisição HTTP:

```
GET https://web.whatsapp.com/%F0%9F%8C%90/pt-br HTTP/1.1
```

O navegador também pode decodificar os símbolos codificados na URI e mostrá-los para o usuário na forma original. Por exemplo, o Chromium faz isso. É algo meramente cosmético; se o usuário copiar a URI, obterá a forma codificada.

O mesmo ocorre no lado do servidor. Se é possível comparar, de forma direta, o caminho da requisição HTTP com símbolos Unicode, então o software deve ser capaz de decodificar os símbolos antes ou durante a comparação.